# Bundling core Node module with Metro

Tags: android, node.js, web3js, metro-bundler

I'm trying to deploy a react-native app to android, the app uses the Web3 library which at a few points uses core node modules (for example a module called 'crypto'), is there any way to bundle the core node modules as if they were a simple npm module?

Ideally I don't want to manually include the core modules since if they were to be updated I'd have to do it manually, and I do not want to create a fork of the Web3 library which uses npm modules instead of the core modules.

Comment: I am having the same issue here! unable to use the libraries that depends on nodejs core modules. have you got any solutions @Terrortorpe

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify

alternatively, use the babel module-resolver plugin to resolve core modules to shims that work in the react native environment, e.g.

- dgram -> react-native-udp
- crypto -> react-native-crypto (or a local module with a smaller subset of the crypto functionality you need)
- fs -> react-native-level-fs
- etc.

See mappings here: https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify/blob/master/browser.json